# Can't open Qt Designer with qgis-designer.bat

Tags: qgis, error, windows, osgeo4w, qt-designer

I'm trying to open Qt Designer using the qgis-designer.bat file, but I'm receiving the following error message

> Windows cannot find `'designer.exe'`. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again.

Any solutions?

My environment: QGIS 3.4.1 installed via OSGeo4W Network installer.

Comment: are you using the osgeo cmd window?

Comment: I can find the .exe at ...\apps\Qt5\bin\designer.exe

Comment: @gHupf i don't find the designer.exe there. That's strange!

Comment: @IanTurton the same with osgeo cmd window as it seems that designer.exe it's lost. Any ideas on what should I do?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling? I use the same version, also installed via OSGeo4W Network installer, so it should be there.

Comment: Hello. I just reinstall and it's ok now. Thanks for support! @gHupf

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, so you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer.exe is found in  ...\OSGeo4W\apps\Qt5\bin\designer.exe if QGIS was installed via the OSGeo4W Network installer. If it is not found there a reinstallation my probably solve your problem.